# Unpublish package from Atmosphere

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I've published a few packages in beta state to Atmosphere. Now, in development it turned out some of them are useless (they were consumed by another one). How can I unpublish them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a temporary, undocumented way to do this:

Log into the atmosphere website with the same details you used to publish your package then in your  javascript console in chrome, safari or firefox run:

```
Meteor.call("deletePackage","<your package name>",function(err,result){
    console.log(result || err)
});
```

Replace `<your package name>` with the name of your package, the same that you could run `mrt add <your package name>` with.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem like there is a way to do this right now. The only non-local functions are `publish` and `release`:

> https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/blob/master/lib/meteorite.js

However, I agree that this is a feature that definitely needs to be added, so that at least some people who want to clean things up have the ability to do so. Otherwise we'll end up in package hell like npm :)

You should open an issue in the meteorite repo.

Answer (score -3):

I think you just remove them from your smart.json file manually and it will "unpublish" them

Comment: unpublish from atmosphere, not locally